# Custom CSS drupal 8

Tags: css, twig, customization, drupal-8, theming

My question is : What's the problem with my theme ?
I just  follow a step by step tutorial, as part of the course on Drupal theming.

I just try to add CSS file and test it with

```
* {background: red}
```

but it doesn't work ! :( i clear the cache.
[arbo][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQmby.png

```
name: Endymion
description: This is the best theme ever
type: theme
core: 8.x
screenshot: endymion.png
regions:
  header: Header
  content: Content
  sidebar_first: Sidebar First
  footer: Footer
  page_top: Page top
  page_bottom: Page bottom
libraries:
  - endymion/global-css
```

and here's my libraries.

```
global-css:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      css/elements.css: {}
      css/layout.css: {}
      css/print.css: { media: print  }
```

Many thanks in advance for your assistance !

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Yes ! I've found the answer :
librairies ---> libraries  french typing error ! :)